# Is there a pandas way of getting the averages between consecutive rows?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(30,3))
df.head()
```

which gives:

```
       0            1           2
0   0.741955    0.913681    0.110109
1   0.079039    0.662438    0.510414
2   0.469055    0.201658    0.259958
3   0.371357    0.018394    0.485339
4   0.850254    0.808264    0.469885
```

Say I want to add another column that will build the averages in column 2: between index (0,1) (1,2)... (28,29).

I imagine this is a common task as column 2 are the x axis positions and I want the categorical labels on a plot to appear in the **middle between the 2 points on the x axis**.

So I was wondering if there is a pandas way for this:

```
averages = []
for index, item in enumerate(df[2]):
    if index < df[2].shape[0] -1:
        averages.append((item + df[2].iloc[index + 1]) / 2)
df["averages"] = pd.Series(averages)
df.head()
```

which gives:

```
       0           1           2        averages
0   0.997044    0.965708    0.211980    0.318781
1   0.716349    0.724811    0.425583    0.378653
2   0.729991    0.985072    0.331723    0.333138
3   0.996487    0.272300    0.334554    0.586686
```

as you can see 0.31 is an average of 0.21 and 0.42.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437657/rolling-mean-on-pandas-on-a-specific-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can do this with `pandas.DataFrame.rolling`. Using your dataframe head as an example:

```
df['averages'] = df[2].rolling(2).mean().shift(-1)
```

returns:

```
>>> df
          0         1         2  averages
0  0.997044  0.965708  0.211980  0.318781
1  0.716349  0.724811  0.425583  0.378653
2  0.729991  0.985072  0.331723  0.333139
3  0.996487  0.272300  0.334554       NaN
```

The `NaN` at the end is there because there is no row indexed 4; but in your full dataframe, it would go on until the second to last row (the average of value at indices 28 and 29, i.e. your 29th and 30th values). I just wanted to show that this gives the same values as your desired output, so I used the exact data you provided. (for future reference, if you want to provide a reproducible dataframe for us from random numbers, use and show us a random seed such as `np.random.seed(42)` before creating the df, that way, we'll all have the same one.)

**breaking it down:**

`df[2]` is there because you're interested in column 2; `.rolling(2)` is there because you want to get the mean of 2 values (if you wanted the mean of 3 values, use `.rolling(3)`, etc...), `.mean()` is whatever function you want (in your case, the mean); finally `.shift(-1)` makes sure that the new column is in the proper place (i.e., makes sure you show the mean of each value in column 2 and the value *below*, as the default would be the value *above*)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, though slightly loopy. But [@sacul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49116088/9209546) is better. I leave this here for reference only.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import zip_longest

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(30, 3))
v = df.values[:, -1]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.mean([i, j], axis=0) for i, j in \
             zip_longest(v, v[1:], fillvalue=v[-1])]), columns=['2_pair_avg']))

#            0         1         2  2_pair_avg
# 0   0.382656  0.228837  0.053199    0.373678
# 1   0.812690  0.255277  0.694156    0.697738
# 2   0.040521  0.211511  0.701320    0.491044
# 3   0.558739  0.697916  0.280768    0.615398
# 4   0.262771  0.912669  0.950029    0.489550
# 5   0.217489  0.405125  0.029071    0.101794
# 6   0.577929  0.933565  0.174517    0.214530
# 7   0.067030  0.452027  0.254544    0.613225
# 8   0.580869  0.556112  0.971907    0.582547
# 9   0.483528  0.951537  0.193188    0.175215
# 10  0.481141  0.589833  0.157242    0.159363
# 11  0.087057  0.823691  0.161485    0.108634
# 12  0.319516  0.161386  0.055784    0.285276
# 13  0.901529  0.365992  0.514768    0.386599
# 14  0.270118  0.454583  0.258430    0.245463
# 15  0.379739  0.299569  0.232497    0.214943
# 16  0.017621  0.182647  0.197389    0.538386
# 17  0.720688  0.147093  0.879383    0.732239
# 18  0.859594  0.538390  0.585096    0.503846
# 19  0.360718  0.571567  0.422596    0.287384
# 20  0.874800  0.391535  0.152171    0.239078
# 21  0.935150  0.379871  0.325984    0.294485
# 22  0.269607  0.891331  0.262986    0.212050
# 23  0.140976  0.414547  0.161115    0.542682
# 24  0.851434  0.059209  0.924250    0.801210
# 25  0.389025  0.774885  0.678170    0.388856
# 26  0.679247  0.982517  0.099542    0.372649
# 27  0.670354  0.279138  0.645756    0.336031
# 28  0.393414  0.970737  0.026307    0.343947
# 29  0.479611  0.349401  0.661587    0.661587
```