# Pandas, approximating a bar plot for large dataframes

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataframe (around 10k rows) of the following form:

```
id   |  voted
123      1.0
12       0.0
215      1.0
362      0.0
...
```

And I want to bar plot this and look at where the values are mostly 0.0 and where they are mostly 1.0. (the order of indices in the first column is essential, as the dataframe is sorted).

I tried doing a bar plot, but even if I restrict myself to a small subset of the dataframe, the plot is still not readable:

[image]

Is there a way to approximate areas that are mostly 1.0 with a single thicker bar, such as we do for histograms, when we set the bins to a higher and lower number?

Comment: What do you want to visualize exactly? Do you have only 0.0 or 1.0?

Comment: yes, the possible values are just 0 or 1

Comment: So the id is sorted somehow and you want to see the density in different areas of the id? so for example if row 1-100 is more 1 or more 0?

Comment: Exactly, to approximate by intervals, so I can get some idea of the density of votes.

Answer (score 0):

As you are searching for an interval approximation for the density of the votes, maybe you can add a [moving average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437657/rolling-mean-on-pandas-on-a-specific-column) to it, :

```
df['ma'] = df['voted'].rolling(5).mean()
```

With this you would have always an average, then you could plot it over the indexes as a line graph, if the value is close to 1 then you know that you have a group of id's which votes with 1.0.