# Calculating Rolling Mean Over Time

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, statistics, rolling-computation

I have a data frame as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-01',2,5],['2019-01-02',15,8],['2019-01-03',1,9],['2019-01-04',10,20],['2019-01-05',5,15]],columns = ['date','data1','data2'])

         date  data1  data2
0  2019-01-01      2      5
1  2019-01-02     15      8
2  2019-01-03      1      9
3  2019-01-04     10     20
4  2019-01-05      5     15
```

I would like to calculate rolling mean for each two days and put the result into a new data frame. For example for date 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-02, the mean for data1 will be 8.5 and mean for data2 will be 6.5, then for date 2019-01-02 and 2019-01-03, the mean for data 1 will be 8 and for data2 will be 8.5. My original dataframe is larger than this, so I would prefer not to do this one by one and I prefer to create loop or if possible vectorization. My aim is to have the below data frame as result

```
         date  data1  data2
0  2019-01-02    8.5    6.5
1  2019-01-03    8.0    8.5
2  2019-01-04    5.5   14.5
3  2019-01-05    7.5   17.5
```

My attempt:

```
def my_attempt(df):
    result = []
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date = start_date.date()
    for i in range(5):
        df1 = df.loc[df['date'].isin([str(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days = i)),str(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days = i) + datetime.timedelta(days = 1))])]
        df1_mean = df1.mean()
    result += df1_mean
    return result
```

THis does not work because df1.mean() will give different format than what I want to get and it is not possible to stack the result by using result+=df1_mean.

Comment: [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling Mean on pandas on a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437657/rolling-mean-on-pandas-on-a-specific-column)

Comment: `df.rolling(2).mean()` or `df[['date']].join(df.rolling(2).mean()).iloc[1:]`

Comment: Why aren’t you using the date-related functionality of Pandas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question seems to be about time, it's best to convert date to `datetime`:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.rolling('2D', min_periods=2, on='date').mean().dropna()
```

Output:

```
      date  data1  data2            
2019-01-02    8.5    6.5
2019-01-03    8.0    8.5
2019-01-04    5.5   14.5
2019-01-05    7.5   17.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use Quang Hoang's solution, but another approach would be:

```
(df.set_index('date').iloc[1:] + df.set_index('date').shift(1).iloc[1:]) / 2
```