# quick operation on blocks of elements in a list/dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, loops, mean

I have a dataframe, and I need to perform the average of the elements of a specific column six-by-six, and then add the obtained column to the dataframe.

---

[here's an example of the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQjFN.png)

---

I'm using a while loop: it works but it takes very long (the list is about 44k rows).

```
while k<df0.shape[0]:
tradRRP[k]=np.mean(df0[['RRP']][k:k+6])
tradRRP[k+1]=np.mean(df0[['RRP']][k:k+6])
tradRRP[k+2]=np.mean(df0[['RRP']][k:k+6])
tradRRP[k+3]=np.mean(df0[['RRP']][k:k+6])
tradRRP[k+4]=np.mean(df0[['RRP']][k:k+6])
tradRRP[k+5]=np.mean(df0[['RRP']][k:k+6])
k=k+6
print(np.format_float_positional(k/df0.shape[0]*100, precision=2), end =" ")
print(' % completed')
```

is there a quicker way to do it?

thanks!

Comment: Use [Pandas rolling mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43437657).

Comment: `df0[['RRP']][k:k+6]` is 1x6 and not 6x6 right?

Comment: yes, is a single value: in fact, is repeated six times because I want the same average every six intervals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a randomized Dataframe `df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(44000,1)), columns={'RRP'})`

I managed to reduce the time a lot by using pandas series. More specifically if you run :

```
step = 6
meanlist = [df0[i:i+step].mean() for i in range(0,len(df0),step) for j in range(step)]
```

you end up with a list of 44k containing Series objects that have the name of the Column, the type and the value for each line of you dataframe. Then you can access this list to get the values you want and add them as a column in the original dataframe.

Compared the two methods on my system:

Original solution:
54.35062098503113 seconds

Pandas series solution:
12.6267409324646 seconds

I hope this helps , have a nice day.