# DataFrame Pandas: create a new column with the average of every possible group of 3 in a series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the most elegant solution to calculate the average/mean of every consecutive possible group of three elements in a series. I have a Dataframe like this

```
Index     Values
0         25
1         12
2         21
3         2
4         6
5         1
6         2
```

Starting from the last element..i would like to create a new column where i have the average of [2,1,6] [1, 6, 2], [6,2,21] ... until the index 0.

So the new column should look like this

```
AVG
NaN
NaN
19.333
11.666
9.666
3.0
3.0
```

My idea was to make a loop and tail(3) the dataframe and remove the last element of the dataframe for each iteration but probably there is a more elegant way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling Mean on pandas on a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437657/rolling-mean-on-pandas-on-a-specific-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `rolling`

```
df['new'] = df.Values.rolling(3).mean()
0          NaN
1          NaN
2    19.333333
3    11.666667
4     9.666667
5     3.000000
6     3.000000
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```