# How to find average temperatures over previous 2 weeks on daily basis in csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am a new coder and have recently been introduced to pandas framework. I have a large csv file with daily average temperatures over few years, that looks like this:

```
   Station  Date    Tmax    Tmin    Tavg
   
   1    5/1/2007    83  50  67
   1    5/2/2007    59  42  51
   2    5/2/2007    60  43  52
   1    5/3/2007    66  46  56
   2    5/3/2007    67  48  58
   1    5/4/2007    66  49  58
   2    5/4/2007    78  51  M
   1    5/5/2007    66  53  60
   2    5/5/2007    66  54  60
   1    5/6/2007    68  49  59
   2    5/6/2007    68  52  60
```

Based on the average temperatures in column Tavg, I need to create another column that will show the average temperatures over previous two weeks on daily basis.

Hope, I made myself clear. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/q/43437657/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you! It's very helpful, answers my question, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As @MarkSetchell suggested, there is a related question that calculates
[Rolling Mean on pandas on a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437657/rolling-mean-on-pandas-on-a-specific-column)

Briefly, Andrew L posted the best answer as

```
  %timeit weather['ma'] = weather['Tavg'].rolling(5).mean()
  %timeit weather['ma_2'] = weather.rolling(5).mean()['Tavg']

  1000 loops, best of 3: 497 µs per loop
  100 loops, best of 3: 2.6 ms per loop
```

The second method is not recommended unless one needs to store computed rolling means on all other columns.